# How to put strings from a file into an array in c

Tags: c, arrays, string

So I have this code:

```
char inte[10];
    while(j<noinput) {
            fscanf(circuit,"%s",inte);
            vararray[count]=inte;
            count++;
            j++;
    }
```

However when I print the contents of the array like this:

```
for (h=0;h<noinput+2;h++){
            printf("%dth variable: %s\n",h,vararray[h]);
    }
```

The elements past the first two (which are reserved for special elements) are all equal to the LAST string that I had taken in from fscanf earlier. I have no idea how one of the strings from fscanf could be equal to multiple slots in the array when I am only setting

```
vararray[count]=inte;
```

Shouldn't this mean that each element of the array will be different since I am incrementing count every time? I am so confused. I also tried doing:

```
 fscanf(circuit,"%s",vararray[count]);
```

But this also did not work and gave me null elements for certain indexes.

Comment: Are all strings in the file of the same length?

Comment: Without the file content being provided as well the question cannot be answered. Please provide the input data you tried the code with.

Comment: I simply tested it on a file containing "a b c"

Comment: Please provide the whole code.

Comment: The whole code isn't needed; whilst this isn't a [mcve], it's pretty close. But, @madmax007, your `vararray` declaration would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You're not copying the string. Here's what's happening:

```
char *vararray[462]; // declare an array of string pointers
char inte[10];       // declare a char array (to function as a string)

for (int i = 0; i < 462; i += 1) {
    // do something
    vararray[i] = inte;
}
```

This is causing all of the items of `vararray` to point to the memory also referred to as `inte`... but you're overwriting that each time! Instead, do something like this:

```
#include <string.h>  // write me at the top, outside main()!

char vararray[462][10]; // declare an array of strings (max length 9)
char inte[10];       // declare a char array (to function as a string)

for (int i = 0; i < 462; i += 1) {
    fscanf(circuit,"%10s",inte);  // use buffer size to make xscanf safer
    strncpy(vararray[i], inte, 9);  // copy inte, making sure not to buffer overflow!
    vararray[i][9] = '\0';  // if inte is too big, a null byte won't be added to the end of the string; make sure that it's there
}
```

This copies the string! Your problem should go away when you do this.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing something too wrong. By "vararray[count]=inte;" you are doing pointer assignment so all of your vararray is getting filled by same string. I am guessing you are new to C so I will answer due to that. Correct way would look something like below

Fixed size solution:

```
char vararray[ROWCOUNT][BUFFERSIZE];
for(count=0; j<noinput; ++count, ++j) {
    fscanf(circuit,"%s",(char*)vararray[count]);
}
```

With dynamic memory management

```
char * vararray[ROWCOUNT];
for(count=0; j<noinput; ++count, ++j) {
    vararray[count] = (char*)malloc(BUFSIZE);
    fscanf(circuit,"%s", vararray[count]);
}
```

I want to warn you in the way of becoming an expert on C nowadays is somewhat madness , i mean unless you have another choice. Examples below I put and the thing you wrote are completely unsafe and unsecure...